# Symfony2.1 - New Sessions stored over and over

Tags: session, symfony

I wonder why each refresh of the page of the website I'm writing, or moving between different pages, creates new session record (I'm storing them in DB instead of using standard solution). In other words, each single click (I'm not using JS / AJAX) creates new record / new session.

Here's my configuration of sessions in config file:

```
session:
    lifetime:       7200
    domain:  MY_SERVER
    handler_id:     session.handler.pdo

parameters:
  pdo.db_options:
    db_table:    session
    db_id_col:   session_id
    db_data_col: session_value
    db_time_col: session_time

services:
  pdo:
    class: PDO
    arguments:
        dsn:            HOST
        user:           USER
        password:       PSWD

session.handler.pdo:
    class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
    arguments: [@pdo, %pdo.db_options%]
```

I tried to use:

```
    auto_start:     false
```

But I'm getting then the following error from Symfony2.1:

```
    The auto_start setting is deprecated. Just remove it from your configuration file.
```

So what should I do to have normal sessions?

**UPDATE** I also used the following:

```
    arguments:
      - "mysql:host=%database_host%;dbname=%database_name%"
      - %database_user%
      - %database_password%
```

that is, my basic Data Base settings for whole project (stored in parameters.yml).

Comment: Make sure your `session.domain` value is correct.

Comment: Thanks Adrien, actually I use "domain: %database_host%" setting. However when I put the exact name of the remote server, the behaviour of the Symfony2.1 is exaclty the same (new sessions and new records in the data base after each refresh or page change). It's really weird to me.

Comment: Hum, and does it work without PDO as the session handler ?

Comment: Yes. The default config for sessions in Symfony2.1 is very short: session: ~. This works well (when storing sessions to the file). What's more interesting, when I change for a while a configuration in order to store sessions to the file, and then I'll back to my PDO configuration, I'm getting new result: permament sessions forever (no matter when I re-open the page, the same session previously opened is continued)!

Comment: Does the `session` table exist ? And I don't see how you tell pdo to select a secific database

Comment: Yes, session table exists. Each refresh of the website means storing a new record into session table. I updated the main subject with what variables I was using (not only "hard-coded" values as mentioned). So,Symfony knows about specific DB. Data are being stored. The problem must be on Symfony'2.1 side.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you do not have session_id set as primary key. Create the session table using (from the documentation, MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE `session` (
    `session_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `session_value` text NOT NULL,
    `session_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

For other databases, see [How to use PdoSessionHandler to store Sessions in the Database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html)